# Flutter can't show the data in text

Tags: flutter, text

I pulled my data and set it with sharedPreferences. And in Future and I can  get the country code when I print it. But I cant show it in my Text. Any İdeas? Here's sample code;

```
  Future<String> getCountryCode() async{
  final countryCodeValue = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   countryCode =countryCodeValue.getString('code');
    print('here $countryCode');
    return countryCode;
}
```

And my text,

```
Text( countryName != null ? countryName['name'] + ' $countryCode': '',   ),
```

P.S; I tried calling my method in initState but it didn't work

Comment: Where are you calling that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setState` in your `getCountryCode` method when the `Future` is done. This will trigger your `build` function to rebuild and thereby showing the `countryCode` in the `Text` widget.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
  Future<String> getCountryCode() async{
  final countryCodeValue = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   // call setState 
   setState((){
   countryCode =countryCodeValue.getString('code');
   });
    print('here $countryCode');
    return countryCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```dart
String countryCode = await getCountryCode();
Text( (countryName != null)? "" + countryName['name'] + ' $countryCode': ''),
```

Comment: When I tried this I got error like 'type 'Future<dynamic> is not subtype of type 'Widget'

Comment: Hey there, add the code for where countryName is defined as the problem seems to stem from that

Comment: return customers.map(
      (item) {
        var _countryName = item['countryName'];
        return MaterialButton(
          onPressed: () {
            storage.setItem('customerRelation', item);
            storage.setItem('countryName', _countryName);
            setState(() {
              countryName = _countryName;
            });
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },

Answer (score 0):

```
Text(countryName != null ? "$countryName['name'] $countryCode" : "",)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var countryCode;
getCountryCode() async{
  final countryCodeValue = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

setState((){
countryCode =countryCodeValue.getString('code');
});
   
    print('here $countryCode');
    

}
```

Now, in your `Text()` widget, do this

```
Text( countryName != null ? countryName['name'] + ' $countryCode': '',   ),
```

Call `getCountryCode()` in `initState()`

Comment: Should I delete my future code and add the getCode part?

Comment: No, don't delete anything, try copy nd pasting, it should work

Comment: Sorry, it still shows null but shows the country code as print...

Comment: Try using only the countryCode in the ```Text```

Comment: still my text value is null

Comment: Where is your getCountryCode()? In another dart file? Or the same file?

Comment: Make sure your text widget is executed after getCountryCode ()

Comment: No I created my getCountry code as Future and called in init, is it a wrong way? btw yes my text comes after getCountryCode ()

Comment: Solved it in the comment below, thank you for your help!